# wordpress showing blank home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a Wordpress custom theme form html by following some tutorial on the internet.

It works fine for a few days and suddenly one day the home page shows as blank. When everyone tries to see the home page it shows a blank page yet other pages work perfectly.

If I typed the url of inner pages in the browser it works, only the home page is not showing.

Then I go to wordpress admin panel and open the home page and save the home page then the problem is solved.

It works for a few days but after that this problem starts again. I don't know why it is happening; maybe because of any update to a plugin.

Note: My home page is a static page like my home page. id is 618 so I created a page in my theme like page-618.php

if i logged in as admin in wp-admin and visit the home page it works perfect

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you looked at your php error logs? Anything in there?

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing any error message? I think in your theme you have a PHP fatal error. That's why you are seeing a blank page. If you are not seeing any error message make sure that in your WordPress folder wp-config.php file

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

in this way, if you have any error message you can see it. After that, if you seeing any error message please shear with us. I hope someone can help you.

Comment: Acualy it is live site and i have to wait until it happen again thanks for your sugestion

Comment: It happen again, and this time i also  use your suggestion but nothing works front page still showing blank